# Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) + Heroku + Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, redis, heroku-postgres

```
2016-12-01T14:26:14.421530+00:00 heroku[run.6714]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2016-12-01T14:25:51+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.07 sample#load-avg-5m=0.09 sample#load-avg-15m=0.075 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15664468.0kB sample#memory-free=11956144.0kB sample#memory-cached=2248760.0kB sample#memory-redis=1421856bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2016-12-01T14:26:35.660410+00:00 heroku[run.6714]: Process running mem=780M(152.4%)
2016-12-01T14:26:35.660501+00:00 heroku[run.6714]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

I'm getting above error on heroku logs. I don't understand the solution and why this error occur.

My server confirmation is high -

1. Professional Dynos
2. 2X Worker
3. Premium Redis Plan - ($15)
4. Database is - Standard 4 Plan

But still getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to see the code with `Name.all.each do |block|` and change it to `Name.find_each do |block|`. This way you can save memory by not loading entire model all at once.

Also try running some benchmark tests so that you can find **memory leaks** that are causing R14 errors.

This link gives you more information https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-memory-use#memory-leaks